# Amazon EMR JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

I am using Amazon EMR Hadoop Hive for big data processing. Current data in my log files is in CSV format. In order to make the table from log files, I wrote regex expression to parse the data and store into different columns of external table. I know that SerDe can be used to read data in JSON format and this means that each log file line could be as JSON object. Are there any Hadoop performance advantages if my log files are in JSON format comparing CSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can process the output of the table (that you created with the regexp) why do another processing? Try to avoid unnecessary stuff.

I think the main issue here is which format is faster to read. I believe CSV will provide better speed over JSON but don't take my word. Hadoop really doesn't care. It's all byte arrays to him, once in memory.

Comment: What kind of processing are you doing on EMR? Maybe something like http://axemblr.com/tool may interest you.